# Nhibernate.linq Session.Query ignore not.lazyload

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I'm using SharpArch, i extended the Repository adding this methods :

```
    public IQueryable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
  var queryable = Session.Query<T>();
  return queryable.Where(expression);
}

 public IQueryable<T> FindAll(ISpecification<T> specification)
{
  var queryable = Session.Query<T>();
  return specification.SatisfyingElementsFrom(queryable);
}
```

Now i can use lambda expressions and specifications with nibernate.linq:

```
 var printers = repository.FindAll(x => x.IpAddress != null).ToList();
```

My problem is that it ignore the Not.Lazyload of my entity map.

instead if i use the FindAll with Dictionary provided by sharpArc it works correctly without lazy load.

Using reflection this is what they do:

```
 public virtual IList<T> FindAll(IDictionary<string, object> propertyValuePairs)
{
  Check.Require((propertyValuePairs != null) && (propertyValuePairs.Count > 0), "propertyValuePairs was null or empty; it has to have at least one property/value pair in it");
  ICriteria criteria = this.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));
  foreach (string str in propertyValuePairs.Keys)
  {
    if (propertyValuePairs[str] != null)
    {
      criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq(str, propertyValuePairs[str]));
    }
    else
    {
      criteria.Add(Restrictions.IsNull(str));
    }
  }
  return criteria.List<T>();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: maybe i could use HQL but i wrote complicated linq query, so i like the possibility to use specification pattern and make some unit test for my specification, without need to make integration tests. I could resolve my problem using Hql or Ado.Net, but i want to know if i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using Session.QueryOver<> instead of Session.Query<>.  I will try and dig up the posting that I read a while back but if I remember correctly Query does not respect all the instructions in the mappings ?yet?.

I'll post more here if I find the relevant article...  hope this helps in the mean time.

Comment: with QueryOver i can't use specifications...am i wrong? The Session.Query works perfectly with spec and Linq, i have only NotLazyLoad problem...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really confusing, but you may want to look into the Fetch() method, assuming you still need help with this.

I am also posting this just in case others come to this question.

Here is [a really great article](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html) on Eager fetching with NHibernate.Linq. I am not sure if this is a problem with your mappings though.